# How to set up the supervisors approval page on the thesis

Tags: spacing, tabularx, alignment, tabulary, page

[image]

My Institute use this format for the supervisor approval. I have tried it. But the the result is not same with the format. The alignment in left side, and the space (spasi) are not same. Please help me to fix this. This is my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=4cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
  \setcounter{page}{5}
  \centering 
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}}}

\vspace{36pt}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{0.5cm}p{11cm}}
Judul&:&Solusi Numerik Model Aliran Massa dalam Sistem Kultivasi \textit{Open Pond Raceways} pada Sawah Alga\\
&&\\
Nama&:&Alphinsi Hugo\\
&&\\
Stambuk&:&118970\\
\end{tabular}\\
\vspace{24pt}
Telah diperiksa dan disetujui untuk diajukan pada Seminar Hasil\\
\vspace{24pt}
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{1.5cm}p{6cm}}
&&Palu, 15 Desember 2019\\
Mengetahui,&&\\
Ketua Jurusan Matematika&&Pembimbing\\
FMIPA UniV&& \\
&&\\
&&\\
&&\\
Name&&Name \\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I think the margin is not work too. And if I merge this code with another `\begin{titlepage}`, the page is not in the even page. My Institute format is every titlepage in even page. I have try `\clearpage` and ``, but it is not working. Many help from anyone.

Comment: Please make your example code cmpilable. Please also clarify " And if I merge this code with another \begin{titlepage}". Do you actually have multiple title pages in your document?

Comment: Could you please clarify the second part of your MWE? You seem to have tried filling in the placeholders of the template in the screenshot. Since I don't understand the language the screensht is in, I personally find it quite hard to compare template and output to see the differences. Could you probably change your code to contain the same placeholder text as the screenshot of the template (especially the part in the second `tabular` environment?)

Comment: @leandriis, yes i have less than 2 titlepage. "Please make your example code cmpilable", I think my code is compatible.

Comment: @leandriism. My code and the sreenshot is not same. Because I don't know how to make like the screenshoot. the word "Spasi" in the screenshoot mean that space between text is. for example 'Judul : [Judul]' and 'Nama : [Nama]' have (2 spasi), that mean space between the text is 2 space. All of sentence with bracket is only a rule of the template.

Comment: The part about the spaces in clearer now. But what does "Mengetahui,"  from your example code refer to? Is it the same as "Pembimbing I"  from  the screenshot?

Comment: Regarding your compilability of your code: Did you try to compile the exact same code from your question? You will recieve at least  an error message about a missing package (`fancyhdr`).

Comment: @leandriis, no it's not same. "Mengetahui" in my code is refer to "Mengetahui" in the screenshot. But I can't make like the screenshot, so I make the code like that.

Comment: @leandriis. I dont receive message about a missing package in my code

Comment: Does https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sySU.png suit your needs?

Comment: @leandriis.  A little bit more. I used margin (top=4cm,right=4cm,bottom and left= 3cm). Can you move the "Palu, 15 Desember 2019" over to the edge near the margin limit? And "Pembimbing II" follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that tabular adds a gap of `\tabcolsep` on each side of a column.  One can remove it on a column basis using `@{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=297mm,paperwidth=215mm,top=4cm,left=4cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
  \setcounter{page}{5}
  \centering 
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont{\textbf{PERSETUJUAN PEMBIMBING}}}

\vspace{36pt}
\begin{flushleft}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% local to flushleft
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}@{:\space}p{11cm}}
Judul&Solusi Numerik Model Aliran Massa dalam Sistem Kultivasi \textit{Open Pond Raceways} pada Sawah Alga\\[2\baselineskip]
Nama&Alphinsi Hugo\\[2\baselineskip]
Stambuk&118970\\
\end{tabular}\\
\vspace{24pt}
Telah diperiksa dan disetujui untuk diajukan pada Seminar Hasil\\
\vspace{24pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{6cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{6cm}}
&Palu, 15 Desember 2019\\[2\baselineskip]
Pembimbing I & Pembimbin II\\[4\baselineskip]
Mengetahui, & Ketua Jurusan Matematika\\
& FMIPA UniV \\[3\baselineskip]
Name&Name \\
\end{tabular*}\\
\vspace{2\baselineskip}%
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering
Mengatahui\\
Ketua Jursan $\dots$\\
FMIPA Universitas Tadulao\\
\vspace{4\baselineskip}%
Name}
\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make like the screenshot?

Comment: You wand (4 spasi) to appear in the text?  Or just to add the centered text at the bottom?

Comment: No. I mean, make "Pembimbing I" ,"Pembimbing II", and "Mengetahui" like the screenshot. Not Only "Pembimbing" and "Mengetahui"

Comment: just add the centered text at the bottom

Comment: You might want to check my spelling.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's work